# Stop Safari zooming in automatically when returning to Safari (iPad)

Tags: ios

On iOS 16 every time I return to the Safari App it will zoom in the page it was displaying before. And every time I have to zoom out again. How can I stop this irritating behavior? Zoom in Accessibility is not switched on.

Comment: That's a failure of the UI, I think there's no way of disabling it.

Comment: I’ve been trying to replicate and have been unsuccessful.  Can you supply additional details?

Comment: I've also tried to replicate it to no avail but I've noticed that when you have a webpage zoomed in (by hand) in split screen and you make it fullscreen, I changes the zoom position. This is obviously normal since the size of the displayed window changes. Is this what you're experiencing?

Comment: It’s not ALWAYS, and I did not zoom anything by hand in advance. Maybe it’s to do with situations where you spend some time out of Safari in other apps, then when you return to Safari it reloads that page, because meanwhile memory has been taken away, so the page is lost, but reloads it zoomed in.  It’s quite annoying!

Comment: @RickJansen Do you have Background App Refresh enabled?

Comment: Background App Refresh : no.

Comment: That might be the reason although I cannot be sure

Comment: Will try background refresh, thanks! (Safari is not in the list of apps you can explicitly switch it on for though)

Comment: Background refresh on, it still happens. Also e.g. in the web version of Whatsapp. Thanks for all your tips, if I ever manage to fix this I’ll tell you.